# IBM AIX Spectre/Meltdown - meaning of affected Lower & Upper Levels

Tags: security, aix

Can someone explain to me the IBM spectre/meltdown patch.
According to [IBM, for example](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1027700).  bos.mp64 is affected and these levels.

```
Fileset                 Lower Level  Upper Level KEY 
---------------------------------------------------------
bos.mp                  5.3.12.0     5.3.12.9    key_w_fs
bos.mp64                5.3.12.0     5.3.12.10   key_w_fs
bos.mp64                6.1.9.0      6.1.9.300   key_w_fs
bos.mp64                7.1.4.0      7.1.4.33    key_w_fs
bos.mp64                7.1.5.0      7.1.5.0     key_w_fs
bos.mp64                7.2.0.0      7.2.0.5     key_w_fs
bos.mp64                7.2.1.0      7.2.1.4     key_w_fs
bos.mp64                7.2.2.0      7.2.2.0     key_w_fs
```

Does this mean only 7.1.4.0 and 7.1.4.33 are affected or everything in between?

Comment: If you feel like this answered your question, please click the check mark. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It means that the entire range of filesets listed are affected: 7.1.4.0 through 7.1.4.33. The closest official description I can find is at https://www.ibm.com/security/secure-engineering/bulletins.html where it says:

> ## Affected products and versions
>
> The affected products and versions section identifies the names of affected IBM Offerings and the versions of those offerings which are affected by the vulnerabilities identified in the security bulletin.